# Stop Word flagging words with underscores as misspelled

Tags: ms-word, spell-checking

Writing semi technical Functional Requirements 7 Business Requirements I often have to add in words that are Column Names or other data that is separated by underscores.

I'd like to stop Word from flagging words with underscores as spelling mistakes.

Have to use word so can't change to something else :)

Ideally not flagging Camel Cased words as spelling mistakes would be great but that I'm fairly sure isn't possible.

I'd like to not flag *fild_name* whilst continuing to flag fild?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the text as No proofing or grammar checked.  Select the text then in Word 2010 this can be found under Review->Language->Set Proofing Language and click the Do Not Check Spelling or grammar box.

You could put this in a macro and then put that as a button on the toobar or quick access toolbar and save clicks.